# How to handle double quotes in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a string assigned to variables and need to declare that in cell using vba.

I tried below code and throws error

```
Dim Var2,Str as string
Var1="OD"
Var2="Leave"
Str="Employee":Var2,"Type":Var1
set ws=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
ws.cells(2,4).value=str
```

My expected output in cells(2,4) should be **"Employee":"Leave","Type":"OD"**

Comment: Maybe add quadruple `"` for each double quote needed to show in the result. Something like `Str = """" & "Employee" & """" & ":" & """" & Var2 & """" & "," & """" & "Type" & """" & ":" & """" & Var1 & """"`

Comment: Use Chr(34) for double quotes and the ampersand for concatenation: Str=Chr(34) & "Employee" & Chr(34) & “:” & Chr(34) & Var2 & Chr(34) etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My expected output in cells(2,4) should be "Employee":"Leave","Type":"OD"

Store the values in an array. It will be much easier to handle as compared to having so many variables.

You can use `Chr(34)` for `"`. Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim Ar(1 To 4) As String
    Dim Strg As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Ar(1) = "OD"
    Ar(2) = "Type"
    Ar(3) = "Leave"
    Ar(4) = "Employee"

    '"Employee":"Leave","Type":"OD"
    Strg = Chr(34) & Ar(4) & Chr(34)
    Strg = Strg & ":" & Chr(34) & Ar(3) & Chr(34)
    Strg = Strg & "," & Chr(34) & Ar(2) & Chr(34)
    Strg = Strg & ":" & Chr(34) & Ar(1) & Chr(34)
    
    'Debug.Print Strg
    
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    ws.Cells(2, 4).Value = Strg
End Sub
```

[image]